# Can someone help me in my Quiz Game using C# unity code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to programming and im having a hard time in my quiz game as of now. There are categories for my game and each question will have a 4 button choices that the user will choose from. The problem is when you press the wrong button once you will go instantly to categories. Can someone help me make an attempt like when the user needs to press 2 wrong button then it will go to categories.

Here's my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelControlScript2 : MonoBehaviour {

// Get references to game objects that should be disabled and enabled
// at the start
GameObject[] toEnable, toDisable;

// References to game objects that should be enabled
// when correct or incorrect answer is given
public GameObject correctSign, incorrectSign;

// Variable to contain current scene build index
int currentSceneIndex;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    // Getting current scene build index
    currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().buildIndex;

    // Finding game objects with tags "ToEnable" and "ToDisable"
    toEnable = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("ToEnable");
    toDisable = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("ToDisable");

    // Disabling game objects with tag "ToEnable"
    foreach (GameObject element in toEnable)
    {
        element.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    }

}

// Method is invoked when correct answer is given
public void RightAnswer()
{
    // Disabling game objects that are no longer needed
    foreach (GameObject element in toDisable)
    {
        element.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    }

    // Turn on "correct" sign
    correctSign.gameObject.SetActive (true);

    // Invoke GotoMainMenu method in 1 second
    Invoke ("LoadNextLevel", 1f);

}

// Method is invoked if incorrect answer is given
public void WrongAnswer()
{
    // Disabling game objects that are no longer needed
    foreach (GameObject element in toDisable)
    {
        element.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    }

    // Turn on "incorrect" sign
    incorrectSign.SetActive (true);

    // Invoke GotoMainMenu method in 1 second
    Invoke ("GotoCategories", 1f);
}


// Method loads next level depending on current scenes build index
void LoadNextLevel()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene (currentSceneIndex + 1);
}

// Method loads Category scene
void GotoCategories()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("Easy");
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a counter and check against it:

```
private int triesLeft;    // Set this to 1 (leave after second) or whatever when a level starts    

// Method is invoked if incorrect answer is given
public void WrongAnswer()
{
    // Disabling game objects that are no longer needed
    foreach (GameObject element in toDisable)
    {
        element.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    }

    // Turn on "incorrect" sign
    incorrectSign.SetActive (true);

    triesLeft--;
    if(triesLeft <= 0)
    {
        // Invoke GotoMainMenu method in 1 second
        Invoke ("GotoCategories", 1f);
    }
}
```

Comment: What it needs to do is when you press the wrong button in the same question twice that's when you will go back to categories.

Example is 
Question 1
Choices: a,b,c,d (a- is the correct answer)
when i press b(wrong button) it will still remain in the scene
and when i press again a c(wrong button) then it will now go back to categories.